# Adding two different group of objects to a list of groups

Tags: java, spring

I have two lists of `String`s and two lists of objects. I need to copy the list of strings to the correspondence list of objects with specific values.

```
public List<Name> retrieveCitiesAndCountries(){
  List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>(); //list of cities
  List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(); //list of countries
  list1 = retrieveListOfCities();
  list2 = retrieveListOfCountries();

  List<Name> namesList = new ArrayList<Names>();
  return namesList;
}
```

Name class

```
class Name{
  String name;
  String attrib;
  ..
}
```

I need to add both lists to `namesList` and add the respective attribs. For example, all cities should have `City` as their attribs and all countries should have `Country` as their attribs.

```
 for(int i=0;i<list1.size();i++){
     Name name = new Name();        
     name.setName(list1.get(i));
     name.setAttrib("City");
     namesList.add(name);
   }

  for(int i=0;i<list2.size();i++){
     Name name = new Name();        
     name.setName(list2.get(i));
     name.setAttrib("Country");
     namesList.add(name);
   }
```

I am wondering if there is any better way to do it.

I use namesList to return in JSON format.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/names")
public @ResponseBody List<Name> retrieveCitiesAndCountries(){
    List<Name> namesList = retrievalServ.retrieveCitiesAndCountries();
    return namesList;
}
```

Comment: Are you on Java 8?

Comment: @h.j.k. no Java 7

Comment: Can you also elaborate more on how your lists are instantiated (will `list1` and `list2` happen to be method arguments, for example), and how is `namesList` used finally?

Comment: Can you also show the complete implementation for `Name`, if feasible, and how it is used? Is it meant to be used generically (in layman terms) to represent either city or country names? How about landmarks? Other geographical features?

Answer (score 2):

The `Name()` class has what I would call a half-assed constructor: it creates an object in a not-quite-initialized state, making it temporarily useless until the setters are called.  If you had a `Name(String name, String attrib)` constructor, then the code would be a lot less cumbersome.

You can also avoid using indexed loops.

```
for (String city : list1) {
    namesList.add(new Name(city, "City"));
}
for (String country : list2) {
    namesList.add(new Name(country, "Country"));
}
```

Comment: thanks, would you elaborate how to pass lists to these loops?

Comment: I already gave you the entire code. What else do you need?

Comment: I got you, you mean I should use contractor to make it easier. I was confused with the work half-assed

Comment: @200_success I am curious about metrics which can help us decide when and how much params to give to constructors and by setter methods.

Comment: @CodeYogi usually it's a choice between constructor or the [builder pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

Comment: @h.j.k. AFAIK that choice comes when we have a large number of arguments to the constructor.

Comment: @CodeYogi yeah, so is that what you are asking, or have I missed your point? :)

Comment: @CodeYogi Setter methods *should not be used separately afterwards* to set values that are expected to be there *during instantiation*. They certainly can be used from within constructors, if so desired.

Comment: @CodeYogi it is (or could be) a matter of immutability.

Answer (score 2):

## Expressive instantiation

Adding to [@200_success](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/107021/24141)'s answer, why not consider `static` methods too, that makes the instantiation a little more *expressive*?

```
public class Name {
    // ...

    public static Name ofCity(String cityName) {
        return new Name(cityName, "City");
    }

    public static Name ofCountry(String countryName) {
        return new Name(countryName, "Country");
    }
}
```

I know you are on Java 7, so you'll still have to rely on the explicit `for`-loop constructs, but here's a sneak peak at how this can be done much more conveniently in Java 8 (when you get the chance to upgrade):

```
public List<Name> retrieveCitiesAndCountries() {
    return Stream.concat(retrieveListOfCities().stream().map(Name::ofCity),
                            retrieveListOfCountries().stream().map(Name::ofCountry))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Here, we use the [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) `Name::ofCity` and `Name::ofCountry` to convert each `String` value we have to a `Stream` of the required type. Finally, we [`concat()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-) both and [`collect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) all the results using [`toList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--).

## What's in a `"City"` or `"Country"`?

> Is it meant to be used generically (in layman terms) to represent either city or country names? How about landmarks? Other geographical features? - [*myself*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/107018/adding-two-different-group-of-objects-to-a-list-of-groups?noredirect=1#comment196231_107018)

The reason why I made that comment is that usually, `String` values are a poor substitute for representing *enumerated values*:

- Prone to human errors (`"city"` vs `"City"`, and that's *"goodbye sleep!"*).
- Can't reliably rely on `==` for comparison (only if you take extreme care to `intern()` everywhere that's required).
- Can't be used in a `switch` pre-Java 7.
- No efficient Collection classes' implementations.
- May not be easy to validate for correct values (depending on use cases).

This is where you may want to consider using an `enum` for such representations, as they are feasible solutions to the points listed above.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the 2 intermediate lists. Plus you could set the `name` and `attrib` directly at the construction of a `Name`.

```
public final List<Name> retrieveCitiesAndCountries() {
    List<Name> namesList = new ArrayList<Names>();

    for(String city : retrieveListOfCities()) {
        namesList.add(new Name(city, "City"));
    }

    for(String country : retrieveListOfCountries()) {
        namesList.add(new Name(country, "Country"));
    }

    return namesList;
}

class final Name {
    final String name;
    final String attrib;

    public Name(String name, String attrib) {
        this.name = name;
        this.attrib = attrib;
    }

    ...
}
```

Again in your JSON service, you can directly return:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/names")
public @ResponseBody List<Name> retrieveCitiesAndCountries() {
    return retrievalServ.retrieveCitiesAndCountries();
}
```

Comment: thanks but I do not get how your answer differs from 200_success' answer?

Comment: @Jack I explicitely declared `Name` immutable, this is a **guarantee** for someone who call `retrieveCitiesAndCountries` that the returned list of `Name` will contain only fully-initialized objects (and not objects in an inconsistent state). Plus I also removed the temporary lists to gain in readability.

Comment: As h.j.k. said, you should also use enums instead of strings ("City", "Country") because it's less error-prone.